# How to add property observer to NSProgress in swift?

Tags: swift, observers, nsprogress

I want to add property observer to NSProgress. I have this code, but it calls only one time.

```
var progress: NSProgress?
{
    didSet
    {
        println(progress!.fractionCompleted)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your observer only fires once is that it's observing for changes on the `progress` variable itself, rather than properties within the `progress` variable (in this case, presumably `fractionCompleted`.)  Since updated to the actual progress of your NSProgress don't involve you setting `progress` to a new `NSProgress`, you only hit the `didSet` once (presumably when you first instantiate it.)

The preferred pattern for observing changes to `NSProgress` is using **Key-Value Observation**, which will fit your use case much more nicely.  You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Comment: yes I know but I think there is a swift style for this case